# elasticsearch group every X values

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation, sequential

Using elasticsearch, I query for a particular field. Is there then a way to aggregate every X values?

For instance, let's say I query 10 documents for field "myField", returning 10 values,

1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4.

Is there a way to aggregate such that every 2 values are averaged, yielding

2.5, 3, 4, 2.5, 2.5 ?

Comment: This is an interesting requirement... Does it matter what order the values are averaged? You could get them in different orders, which would change each average. I'm not sure there is a way to do this, but is there a reason you wouldn't do it application-side?

Comment: Yes, I would order the values beforehand. I could do it application-side, yes, but for scalability purposes I was wondering if it could be accomplished via elasticsearch. I may eventually have millions of documents to aggregate.

Comment: I think you could set this up with a scripted metric aggregation, but it would be a total hack. Not sure about repeatability.

Comment: A "scripted metric aggregation" using elasticsearch or application-side? ie. at what point would this aggregation come in, and what would it look like, @SloanAhrens?

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some interesting--and perhaps inadvisable--stuff with [scripted metric aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). They let you define map-reduce scripts that run against your documents. You can get yourself in trouble with this, of course.

But just to see if I could do it, I set up a simple, single-shard index with the data you provided:

```
PUT /test_index
{"settings": {"number_of_shards": 1}}

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"num":1}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"num":4}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"num":2}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"num":4}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"num":5}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"num":3}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"num":3}
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{"num":2}
{"index":{"_id":9}}
{"num":1}
{"index":{"_id":10}}
{"num":4}
```

Then I can average every two documents like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "profit": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "_agg['nums'] = []; _agg['avgs'] = [];",
                "map_script" : "_agg.nums.add(doc['num'].value); if(_agg.nums.size() == 2){ _agg.avgs.add((_agg.nums[0] + _agg.nums[1])/2.0); _agg['nums'] = [];}", 
                "combine_script" : "return _agg.avgs",
                "reduce_script" : "return _aggs"
            }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "profit": {
         "value": [
            [
               2.5,
               3,
               4,
               2.5,
               2.5
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

It doesn't seem to respect sorting order in the query, though the outcome is deterministic as far as I can tell.

What I did here only works with a single shard; you could probably generalize it somehow if you wanted to tinker with it long enough.

Also, **big fat disclaimer:** doing this in production might be a bad idea. You'd want to test this sort of thing out on small data sets first before you potentially crash your cluster with out-of-memory errors. Also only use scripting if your cluster isn't open to the big bad Internet.

Here is some code I used to play around with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/c31f089e63200127fd9ca09992004db8bb11b890

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting some time into this! Unfortunately I think because of the problems you mentioned (only working with a single shard, and not respecting sorting order), I'll have to do this application-side. Hoping this solution will help me or someone else in the future!